# Amazon-CloudWatch tag is missing

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

What's the process to propose a new tag?
I see lots of Amazon related tags referring to specific products, and found that the CloudWatch tag is missing (and couldn't add it due to lack of reputation).

Answer (score 2):

For the record, tag [amazon-cloudwatch](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) meanwhile exists.

The process is to simply wait until a user with enough reputation creates one or ask one to do it, as you implicitly tried here - I've seen users asking other participants in such a question to create the appropriate tag, which seems to have a comparatively high chance of immediate success due to the addressed posters apparent interest in the subject at hand.